# Mock os.makedirs within class using fixtures

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How do I test `os.makedirs` which sits within a class that I instantiate in a fixture?

`get_images.py`

```
class Images:
    def __init__(self, username: str) -> None:
        self.output_location = os.path.join(
            r"C:\Users", self.username, r"Pictures\WindowsSpotlight"
        )

    def create_folder(self) -> None:
        if not os.path.exists(self.output_location):
            os.makedirs(self.output_location)
```

Tests which return `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'f_get_images'`:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch
import unittest

from src.get_images import Images

@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def f_get_images():
    return Images("test")

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("f_get_images")
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('f_get_images.exists')
    @patch('f_get_images.makedirs')
    def test_create_folder(self, mock_make_dirs, mock_exists) -> None:
        mock_exists.return_value = True
        f_get_images.create_folder()

        mock_make_dirs.assert_called_with()
```